# Reading a GPIO port from C using wiringPi on a rpi 2b always says there is no signal

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, gpio, wiringpi

I am trying to read a GPIO port from a raspberry pi 2B with C. I am using the wiringPi module and I have written a little program to try it out but it just always prints 0, even if I directly connect the pin to 3.3 or 5V. I also tried pulling it up but then it just always says 1, even when I try connecting it directly to ground. When I tried to read the pin with python it worked correctly so I am at a loss as to what is wrong. The code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

void main(){
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(4, INPUT);
    pullUpDnControl(4, PUD_DOWN);
    printf("%d", digitalRead(4));
}
```

I am running raspbian 7 (wheezy)

Comment: *it just always prints 0, even if I directly connect the pin to 3.3 or 5V. I also tried pulling it up but then it just always says 1, even when I try connecting it directly to ground.* - these two are contradicting each other.

Comment: No, the code as I have put it pulls it down and makes it print 0, but if I change the code so it pulls it up, it always prints 1 @EugeneSh.

Comment: Then you are not using the pin you want to. Or having some other HW problem

Comment: But I tried reading the same pin in python and it worked @EugeneSh.

Comment: which pin is it? .

Comment: GPIO pin 4, which is pin 7 on the pi or the 3rd one after the square connector @EugeneSh.

Comment: Pin 7 is GPIO7, which is WiringPi 7 according to https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/pins/

Comment: Should you be calling `wiringPiSetupGpio (...)` first?

Comment: There's also this `this function needs to be called with root privileges`

Comment: @clebanc thanks so much, that now works with wiringPiSetupGpio(). I hadn't realised I had to use that as well as wiringPiSetup()

Comment: You could use `wiringPiSetup` with a different mapping. http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/

Comment: @EugeneSh. Here is a rpi2b pinout which makes gpio4 as pin7 http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/var/rpi/storage/images/media/images/raspib-gpio/12356-1-eng-US/RasPiB-GPIO_lightbox.png